# EVisitor (class TV) evisitor (subclass 651) visa

Tags: visas, australia

I have the above visa (date of application 10th October 2016)  I arrive in Australia on 1st March 2017.  I leave Australia on 12th April 2017.  My visit is help my daughter with her wedding preparation on 8th April.  She has now asked that I come earlier.  If I can find an earlier flight where do I stand with this visa - do I have to change it and if so how?  Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

The eVisitor visa is valid from the date it is *granted* for twelve months, and you can't stay for longer than three months during a visit:

> You can stay in Australia for up to three months on each visit within 12 months from the date your eVisitor is granted. ([source](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-))

So if you have a eVisitor that was granted in October, you are okay to change your travel dates as long as you're not going to stay longer than three months.